# Factor Analysis vs PCA

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, exploratory-factor-analysis

Could someone please explain when FA is used or when PCA is used, as I understood FA do dimensionality reduction, however PCA - the main goal is the same. Then which one should I use and in which cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Principal component analysis (PCA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis)** is a technique for reducing the dimensionality of such datasets, increasing interpretability but at the same time minimizing information loss. It does so by creating new uncorrelated variables that successively maximize variance.

**[Factor analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_analysis)** is a way to condense the data in many variables into a just a few variables. For this reason, it is also sometimes called “dimension reduction.” You can reduce the “dimensions” of your data into one or more “super-variables.”

**PCA** is used to decompose the data into a smaller number of components and therefore is a type of **Singular Value Decomposition (SVD)**. **Factor Analysis** is used to understand the underlying 'cause' which these factors (latent or constituents) capture much of the information of a set of variables in the dataset data.

For More,

[What are the differences between Factor Analysis and Principal Component Analysis?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/1576/260797)

> In terms of a [simple rule of thumb](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/1579/260797), I'd suggest that you:
>
> 1. Run factor analysis if you assume or wish to test a theoretical model of latent factors causing observed variables.
> 2. Run principal component analysis If you want to simply reduce your correlated observed variables to a smaller set of important independent composite variables.